# Do you need to sterilize jars when making yogurt?

Tags: yogurt

I recently bought an [Instant Pot](http://instantpot.com/) and am curious about its much-touted yogurt-making capabilities. From [this video](https://youtu.be/cHca_wJJg48) it looks simple enough. What the video doesn't address, though, is the question of sterilization. Do I need to sterilize the yogurt jars, as though I were making jam? My guess is no, since you can also make yogurt in the steel liner, which isn't sterile, but it seems prudent to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clean with soap and water. Sterilization is not necessary.